# What is "status.stackexchange.com"?

Tags: discussion

Due to my curiousity, I stumbled across this "status" site.  But it's contents are locked behind a login wall, which I'm guessing isn't open to normal users.

What is this "status.stackexchange.com" used for?

(So you don't have to copy and paste: http://status.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What is this "status.stackexchange.com" used for?

status.stackexchange.com is our [Opserver](https://github.com/opserver/Opserver) instance (Opserver has been open sourced by us).

This is our internal dashboard, where we monitor our different systems.

---

For publicly available information, you can use [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net) or follow [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) on twitter.

Comment: Yep and it clearly says "This site is for monitoring status of the Stack Exchange network" in the footer. :)

Comment: There should be a link in `status.stackexchange.com` pointing to @StackStatus or `stackstatus.net` :)