# Link from status.stackexchange.com to stackstatus.net

Tags: feature-request, maintenance

"status" subdomain is rather typical place to have public availability metrics on. Both [Github](https://status.github.com) and [Reddit](https://status.reddit.com) redirect to public status page when I try this subdomain.

StackExchange however has a [private site](https://status.stackexchange.com) at "status" subdomain.

Like with many other big sites (that are not social networks), there is also [public status tracker](https://www.stackstatus.net/) for StackExchange. However, "status.stackexchange.com" only has a lonely Okta login button, making impression that there is no public status, only a private one.

I think it would be helpful to also offer link to [Stack Overflow Global Status Page Status](https://www.stackstatus.net/) at [status.stackexchange.com](https://status.stackexchange.com). It was suggested [earlier as a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258579/what-is-status-stackexchange-com#comment905738_258581), but did not receive enough discussion.